# "Invert" Axis on Matplotlib / Seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Good evening/morning/evening !
I am only a leisure programmer so I appologise if this question has been answered on here before under a different title, I didn't know what to search for.

If you see below I have plotted two graphs, one a 2d and the other a 3d using matplotlib. [image]

My issue is that I wish for (0,0) to be in the bottom left corner and a step to the right to be +1 and a step upwards to be -1. Instead of having x increase and y decrease. If it is needed I will post the entire code for these plots but they have both been done conventionally with seaborn.heatmap(z) and ax.plot_surface(x,y,z).

Also I am using the following line I found on here: ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 1)
Could someone please explain the parameters of this function to me I am struggling to understand what they mean.

Any help is greatly appreciated and again I apologise if this has been posted before :)

Comment: [`add_subplot()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html?highlight=add_subplot#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_subplot) has the structure (nrows, ncols, index) meaning the index in a grid of number of rows x number of columns. The index is counted row-wise from the left top and obviously cannot exceed nrows x ncols. As for your question: It is not clear to me what you try to achieve but [the suggested axis invert](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/axes_api.html#axis-limits) function is probably what will be of help to you.

Answer (score 4):

In matplotlib:

If you want to invert the x-axis:

```
ax.invert_xaxis()
```

If you want to invert the y-axis:

```
ax.invert_yaxis()
```

If you want to invert the z-axis:

```
ax.invert_zaxis()
```

I'm pretty sure that these functions will work in seaborn as well, since it is built on top of matplotlib!